# .NET Garbage Collection Tuning for Objects Known to Have a Long Life

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

I'm working in a .NET application where we have a very large cache implemented with a Dictionary.  I remove things from the cache via a TTL and a reaper that periodically checks for expired items.  A given common TTL value will be on the order of hours.  Considering this, is there anything I can do each object as I put it into cache so that I don't have to go through Gen0 and Gen1 each time I want to cache something for hours?

EDIT:  I should specify my question better.  I understand how .NET garbage collection works and I know it's good at it's job.  I agree that in ideal situations, you would want it work work exactly as it was designed.  Specifically though, I'd like to know if there is any way to have control over how it works for this exact scenario.

Comment: Why would you need to tune it? Can you describe the exact problem that you are having with garbage collection?

Comment: +1 agree.  Since the objects are long-term, they will get promoted and that's the way the GC is designed.

Comment: Agreed. I don't pay much attention to garbage collection myself, but this is sort of screaming "premature optimization" at me.

Comment: @0xA3 - It seems if you know an object is going to be long-living, you wouldn't want it in Gen0 or Gen1 at all.  Doing so would mean that (for a period of time) GC is going to be checking it when it doesn't need to.  The algorithm for GC in .NET implies that an object "proves" it is long living by surviving Gen0 and Gen1 collections.  It seems like in my case it'd be an advantage to go straight to Gen2.

Comment: @Daniel - This is certainly not premature.  I'm trying to optimize an existing system which is having memory issues and high GC usage on the processor.

Comment: @L. Moser: The high GC usage is going to likely be from Gen2 collections - Gen0 and even Gen1 collections tend to not cause heavy GC usage in profiling.  This is more likely a true leak (your cache not removing cleanly) or that you have too many items in your cache (in which case maybe you need to shorten the TTL?)

Comment: @Reed - So Gen2 collections are more expensive than collections done in Gen1 and Gen0?

Comment: @LJM: Yes, since Gen2 collections traverse all three generations + the LOH.  Gen0 collections are incredibly cheap.  That's the main reason the GC is generational - it avoids the expensive collections most of the time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object will promote into Gen2 relatively quickly since your Dictionary will always leave it rooted.

There isn't an API that lets you allocate directly into a different generation, but I doubt that this will have a real-world impact on performance, since it really doesn't take long for objects to get promoted if they're staying rooted.  Any cache with objects that have multi-hour lifetimes shouldn't be ones that are being allocated frequently, so the savings you'd receive even if this were possible would be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

If the cache is large, you may want to look at pooling the objects in the cache, instead of getting rid of them after a time and putting new ones in. Otherwise what you're doing is making garbage out of objects that have been tucked into a corner of Gen 2, and which the GC may not get around to collecting for a long time. This can lead to an increased memory footprint for the application, caused by objects which are not in use but also not being collected until the GC is put under enough stress to warrant digging them out.

Obviously this is more relevant to the scenario of running this instance for a long time, but if you're throwing things away after a few hours, it sounds like that's what you're doing.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by pooling the objects?

Comment: Instead of allocating new objects and placing them in the cache, allocate an appropriate number of cached objects up front when the process starts, and change the values on these objects as you want them to cache different things over time. So you don't throw the objects out, you simply change their values when you need to cache something new. This a general overview, but you can find a longer description at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern. The idea is you stop the allocate/garbage collect churn - the pooled object never die, so the GC isn't affected by the pool.